# Logical meaning of the word "understand"

Tags: etymology, prepositions, prefixes

To understand something means to be aquainted with it, to know it very well, know how it "ticks". This is one of the basic words that has a direct "meaning" in mind.

However, if we "dissect" it, is seems like it means to *stand under* something. Isn't knowing something would logically be called *abovestand* and not *understand*, since when you are under something, you are less informed about it then when you are above it.

This may seem senseless to you, but I am sure a native English speaker will get the idea of what I am trying to say. Why *under*, not *above*?

Comment: haha you certainly rattled the etymologists' cages there! I'm not one - I just copied a few bits into my answer to illustrate my basic point that the "understanding" you ended up with probably wasn't going to be what you'd originally expected.

Comment: Thank you. The reason I asked is because in Russian we have pretty much similar "misconception" and now after reading the answers I understand that the same way we have "under" that means "stand behind". This is kind of fantastic.

Comment: Off-topic: In Japanese, the character for "divide" is the same used for "understand" which is why I felt it translates more closely with "rationalize" (ignoring the negative connotation).

Comment: The link in Fumblefingers' answer is what you should be reading: it provides the most detailed and thorough explanation of the possibilities. In summary: we do not know how exactly *under + stand* came to mean *understand,* i.e. there is no answer yet.

Comment: @zzzzBov, that's interesting about divide and understand. I'm not sure how that ties into rationalize, because normally that is the exact opposite. Rationalize means an "attempt to explain or justify with logical, plausible reasons, even if these are not true...", so it does not mean "divide" (i.e. dissect) or "understand". One way of smoothing over something (so people won't start dissecting it) is rationalization.

Comment: @ArlenBeiler - my attempt to try to explain such an ancient and powerful language as Japanese may be very childish, but in their language "Understand" and "Divide" may be synonymous due to thinking that to "know something" you need "to get to the insides of it" therefore dividing it. Division of solid would reveal it's internal structure and let you "know it", stand within it.

Comment: @MaximV.Pavlov: Cf. "analyse", from Greek *luô*, which means "to loosen, solve".

Comment: @ArlenBeiler, `Rational numbers` are numbers that can be expressed as a ratio, which is division. When rationalizing, one typically separates the subject into smaller, simpler ideas. Simplifying ideas can be done incorrectly as easily as simplifying fractions, which leads to the negative connotation of "rationalization" as oversimplification to falsehood.

Comment: @Maxim V. Pavlov: That snippet from OED as quoted by John is certainly relevant to "getting to the insides of" - O.E. *under*, from PIE *nter-* "between, among" (cf. Skt. *antar* "among, between," L. *inter* "between, among," Gk. *entera* "intestines;" see inter-)

Comment: A lot of these Latin metaphors have been taken over into English.

Comment: My allied question on Linguistics may aid you: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/12130/how-does-the-prefix-entre-in-frenchs-entreprendre-compare-with-the-prefix/12131#12131.

Comment: Understanding comes from the word Upanishad, in Sanskrit. To "stand under" someone is to learn from a guru, who typically sits above the sisya.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not *"logical"*. It's ***metaphorical***. Here's the etymology from the OED:

> [OE. *understondan, -standan* (under-1 8 a), = OFris. *understonda*, MDa. *understande*, MSw. *undi(r)standa*, OIcel. (as a foreign word) *undirstanda*. Cf. MLG. *understân* to understand, to step under, MDutch *onderstaen* (Dutch -*staan*), MHG. *understân*, -*stên* (G. *unterstehen*), to take upon oneself, to venture, presume, etc.
>
> With a different prefix, the same use of *stand* appears in OE. *forstandan*, OS. *farstandan*, OHG. *far-, firstantan* (*firstân*), and MHG. *verstân, -stên* (G. *verstehen*), MDutch *verstaen* (Dutch -*staan*). In the 15th and 16th cents. three forms of the past participle were current, viz. (a) the original *understanden* (also -*stonden*), in use till about 1550; (b) the reduced form of this, *understande* (-*stonde*), -*stand* (-*stond*), common till about 1575, and surviving into the 17th cent.; (c) the new form *understanded* (-*stonded*), very common from about 1530 to 1585. The occurrence of *understanded* in the Thirty-Nine Articles, xxxv, in the phrase `understanded of the people', has given rise to recent echoes of it, especially in journalistic use. The modern form *understood* came into use in the latter part of the 16th cent., and was usual by 1600. ]

So *understand* means to stand under (we would now say "stand behind" as a more common idiom), to know well, to have trust in, to have personal confidence in, etc. To say one understands a task, a trade, a fact, an idea, a job, the meaning of a word, or a person means all that. The personal aspect of the word is pre-eminent.

Comment: This explanation does not really follow from the quotation given. Upon following the link in Fumblefingers' answer, it will be seen that there are several competing theories, under which "stand behind" is not at all the most prominent one (pun intended). "Stand among" has more support; another major theory refers to a certain kind of analogy/contamination within the semantic field.

Comment: It's the same metaphor in either case, representing slowly changing social understandings over several millennia. The fact is that the "under-" part is so different from the word _under_ that it can come as a shock that it's there. It's become as invisible as the _auf-_ 'up' in German _aufhören_ 'to stop'; or the _hemos_ 'we have' in Spanish _veniremos_ 'we will come'. That's what happens to words as they succumb to the binding energy of the verb and plunge in to become affixes, like _useta coulda shoulda wanna oughta._

Comment: No, it is probably *not* the same metaphor. The other "under" meant "among", not "under". And there may not be any real metaphor concerning "standing" in the theory that mentions semantic blending. I highly recommend reading the link, it is quite fascinating! Too bad the book only treats relatively few words; but then it is only an introduction.

Comment: There are treatments of the etymological metaphorical sense of _stand;_ [this one](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/style.pdf), for instance.

Comment: Perhaps there is a relationship between *underlay* and *underlie* that can also strengthen the metaphor argument.

Answer (score 9):

You can't assume a current word superficially constructed from multiple elements which are *also* current words can necessarily be easily "deconstructed" from current meanings of the components.

From OED, it appears English imported *understand* wholesale from Middle Dutch **onderstaen** *(to take upon oneself, to venture, presume)*. But Old English also had the same use of "stand" in **forstandan**.

From [pp 210-214, *An Analytic Dictionary of English Etymology, An Introduction* (2008)](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=_m7k1Oi-cakC&pg=PA213&lpg=PA213&dq=OE.%20forstandan&source=bl&ots=eva6zDFu-l&sig=cMVw1_cq4loeXl44o2yFdnLiZqw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=3cNgT7zRNciw0QWfxMzEDw&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=OE.%20forstandan&f=false):

> *OE. **forstandan**, OHG firstantan, firstan 'verstehen' may have meant primarily 'stand before,' and hence 'watch, observe, perceive'*. And just as the "stand" component semantically relates to *perception, standpoint* rather than physical posture, the "under" component is actually more *among, within* rather than *beneath, supporting*.

Be warned that if you follow the above link, you're looking at six pages of densely-packed analysis of the etymology of *understand*; attempts to summarise it here are somewhat futile.

I'm not sure any of this will really help OP. It just serves as a reminder that *language evolves* - things which look similar today may be unrelated, and things which look dissimilar may have a common origin.

Comment: Very, very interesting link. My summary of it is thus: we do not know. It admits that all we have are various alternative speculations.

Comment: @Cerberus: I think this is the second time in a week I find myself referencing [your answer re "supposed to"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21706), and the wretched [think/believe disparity](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/). Like them, *"understand"* is a word much used in contexts like [the "hard problem"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_problem_of_consciousness), volition, belief, and all those other things where hardly anyone even knows what exactly they think, let alone is able and willing to articulate their thoughts (whatever "thoughts" actually are! :)

Comment: True: "understand" can have an added meaning in the realm of desirability ("don't worry, she will understand"). I guess it is a subjective kind of modality.

Comment: @Cerberus: Not to mention the bank manager who ushers you into his office and starts off with *I understand you've applied for a loan*. Then clearly demonstrates that he *doesn't* understand, by making you explain in great detail exactly *why* you want the money, and *how* you're going to repay it. The only thing the bank manager understands at the start of that little chat is that *he's got all the money*.

Comment: German has *fürstehen* so I'd hazzard a guess that "*stand before*" is an overstatement; *to stand for sth.* seems a logical consequence *if one understands sth.*. German does have *verstehen* "forestand, understand" as well, so I'm sure my interpretation is as well misleading. But we do have *vorstehen*, *Vorsteher* "foreman", now literally somebody who leads in front, but cp Lat *phore* "to speak", thus eventually *spokes person*. I answered elsewhere (which I should move here), that spread of the cristian faith informed Ger *unterstellen*, for what it's worth. So loan from Norm. is possible

Answer (score 4):

[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=understand&searchmode=none) presents a plausible explanation:

> **understand**
> O.E. *understandan* "comprehend, grasp the idea of," probably lit. "stand in the midst of," from *under* + *standan* "to stand" (see ***stand***). If this is the meaning, the *under* is not the usual word meaning "beneath," but from O.E. *under*, from PIE *nter-* "between, among" (cf. Skt. *antar* "among, between," L. *inter* "between, among," Gk. *entera* "intestines;" see ***inter-***).

It goes on to give a second explanation which ties *understand* to the current word *under*:

> That is the suggestion in Barnhart, but other sources regard the "among, between, before, in the presence of" sense of O.E. prefix and preposition under as other meanings of the same word. "Among" seems to be the sense in many O.E. compounds that resemble *understand*, e.g. *underniman* "to receive," *undersecan* "to investigate," *underginnan* "to begin." It also seems to be the sense still in expressions such as *under such circumstances*.
>
> Perhaps the ultimate sense is "be close to," cf. Gk. epistamai "I know how, I know," lit. "I stand upon." Similar formations are found in O.Fris. (understonda), M.Dan. (understande), while other Germanic languages use compounds meaning "stand before" (cf. Ger. verstehen, represented in O.E. by forstanden). For this concept, most I.E. languages use figurative extensions of compounds that lit. mean "put together," or "separate," or "take, grasp" (see comprehend). O.E. oferstandan, M.E. overstonden, lit. "over-stand" seem to have been used only in literal senses.

Answer (score 4):

The prefix *under* in *understand* does not mean "beneath", but rather appears to be from an unrelated root mean "among". Allow me to quote [etymonline.com](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=understand&allowed_in_frame=0):

> O.E. *understandan* "comprehend, grasp the idea of," probably lit. "stand in the midst of," from under + standan "to stand" (see stand). If this is the meaning, the under is not the usual word meaning "beneath," but from O.E. *under*, from PIE *nter- "between, among" (cf. Skt. antar "among, between," L. inter "between, among," Gk. entera "intestines;" see inter-).
>
> That is the suggestion in Barnhart, but other sources regard the "among, between, before, in the presence of" sense of O.E. prefix and preposition under as other meanings of the same word. "Among" seems to be the sense in many O.E. compounds that resemble understand, e.g. underniman "to receive," undersecan "to investigate," underginnan "to begin." It also seems to be the sense still in expressions such as under such circumstances.
>
> Perhaps the ultimate sense is "be close to," cf. Gk. epistamai "I know how, I know," lit. "I stand upon." Similar formations are found in O.Fris. (understonda), M.Dan. (understande), while other Germanic languages use compounds meaning "stand before" (cf. Ger. verstehen, represented in O.E. by forstanden). For this concept, most I.E. languages use figurative extensions of compounds that lit. mean "put together," or "separate," or "take, grasp" (see comprehend). O.E. oferstandan, M.E. overstonden, lit. "over-stand" seem to have been used only in literal senses.

Answer (score 4):

According to the extremely useful and interesting *Online Etymology Dictionary* (www.etymonline.com), *understand* comes from old English. In those days, *under* did not mean "beneath", but "among, between", a semantic thread that goes all the way back to the Sanskrit word *antar*.

But the dictionary also states another hypothesis, which is directly linked to your opinion, but rather inversely (cf. Gk. epistamai): "I stand upon."

It's good to keep in mind that words have old and forgotten ancestors. The link between the new and the old might remain, but most often in an exquisitely convoluted fashion.

Answer (score 2):

You might be getting tripped up by thinking that ***under*** means ***below*** or ***beneath***.  Sure, ***under*** **can** mean the opposite of ***over*** or ***above***, but there are several [other](http://www.onelook.com/?w=under&ls=a) meanings of under as well.

Several words begin with *under*- (such as *undertones*, *understudy*, *understate*, *undertake*) - not always implying physical proximity beneath something else.

(See link provided above).

Comment: So, I had the same question.  After reading all of these (pretty good) responses I think I get it.  So Understand is to Stand Under (the surface) of a thing, which would be inside of it.

Answer (score 2):

The direct answer to your question is that the meaning of 'understand' is not a composition of its parts, as you have well noticed, and this is a general feature of natural languages that it is not logical or literal. It might start off literally (as in a constructed language) but once a generation has gone by, everything is metaphorical. For example there are similar words 'undertake', 'forget', 'withhold' whose meanings are only tangentially related to their parts.

As to the particular phenomenon of 'understand', [etymonline has a speculative derivation](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=understand) where 'under' really comes from the PIE root for 'inter' or between, thus an attempt at preserving some literal connection in the ancient word.

For comparison as to how other languages do it for 'understand', there is quite a bit of illogical non-literal metaphor: 'com-prendre' in French and Spanish (literally 'take with'), 'по-нимать' (Russian - 'takes on'), 'κατα-λαμβάνω' (Greek 'hold down'). Of course all these examples are European so there may be an area influence (Sprachbund). I was unable to confirm examples in Indian or Chinese (most terms in Chinese really are pairs of syllables each with their own stand alone meaning) so often a metaphorical extension occurs anyway.

Comment: It is spelled κατα-λαμβάνω, and it rather means "seize and hold down" if translated very literally. There is also συν-ίημι, "set together", and ἐπ-ίστᾰμαι, "stand on/by".

Comment: I'd suppose "*comprendre*" -- *take together, gather* -- but if *take with* is your *take away* that works for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

[This Reddit post](https://old.reddit.com/r/etymology/comments/82tj3n/where_did_the_under_come_from_in_under_arrest/dvd5u8n/) refers to an explanation in *Story of Human Language*. Please edit this, if you know at which moment in time or which lecture.

> If you like John McWhorter (I do, but I can admit some shortcomings in his conclusions as a result of his enthusiasm), he discusses this in one of his Great Courses lectures, though I forget which one. The conclusion he comes to is that understanding means that you are “standing under/amid the information”, meaning you know it well.