# "could have" vs "could"

Tags: grammar

We say that could is sometimes the past of can. If that's true then why can't we use it in the following context.

> They didn't let us. We could walk.

Instead we say:

> They didn't let us. We could have walked.

But we can say:

> Listen! I can hear something.
>
> I listened and I could hear something. Why not "I listened and I could have heard something"

Comment: Why the down vote? Isn't this a valid question or what? Or is it that people have started to screw up things here.

Comment: I imagine the downvotes are because your question as presented doesn't give any meaningful context for the first two examples, which can both be valid in certain contexts. The issues of usage involved here are quite tricky, as I expect you realise by now, but the way you asked doesn't do the question any favours. If it gets any more downvotes and you don't know how to fix things, perhaps I'll edit the question to improve it.

Comment: This site is full of boring people. They downvote you, don't worry about them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per the top answer to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21706/why-do-we-say-was-supposed-to-for-should-have), there's a tendency in many languages for words to shift in meaning between *probability and desirability*, where *probability* covers what [englishclub.com](http://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-conditional_6.htm) define as *zero/first/second/third* conditional modes *(certain/probable/possible/impossible)*.

The "core" sense of *can/could* involves *capability*, which is part of the *probability/desirability* issue, so along with other [modal verbs](http://www.englishpage.com/modals/modalintro.html) it has many inconsistencies and idiomatic meanings.

---

Turning to OP's specific examples...

*"They didn't let us. We could walk."* is perfectly valid, given an appropriate context. For example, we tried to borrow wheelchairs from the hospital, but because we were capable of walking they wouldn't let us have them.

*"They didn't let us. We could have walked."* is harder to contextualise sensibly, but it can be done. Maybe we were in a pub where they wouldn't let us smoke indoors, and we were so angry we could have walked [out] (but we didn't, because we wanted a drink more than a smoke).

*"I listened and I could hear something."* is a fairly straightforward usage, where *"I could hear"* emphasises *I was able to hear* more than a simple *"I heard"* would.

*"I listened and I could have heard something."* is a more complex usage. In this case, *could* doesn't have the sense of *having been capable of hearing*. It's being used to indicate a (relatively low) degree of probability. So low, in fact, that the speaker is expressing uncertainty as to whether he did in fact hear anything or not. But in that particular case, it's at least possible something was heard.

The list of alternative meanings attaching to *could*, and *could have* could and probably does fill a book. As Lynn has noted, present/past tense *may* imply different meanings, but...

- **It was so loud I could hear it** *(loud enough that I was able to, and did in fact hear it)*
- **It was so close you could touch it** *(but you didn't, you probably weren't even there)*
- **It was so close you could have touched it** *(again, you didn't actually touch it)*
- **I was so upset I could have cried** *(but by implication I didn't actually cry)*

It's important to note that the second and third examples there mean *exactly the same thing* in most contexts. Only a pedant would worry about mixing the tenses - you *didn't* touch it anyway, so it really makes no difference *when* you didn't do what you never did.

TL;DR: Present tense *could* often means you **are** capable of doing something - and possibly that you have just done, are doing, or are just about to do it. Past tense *could have* often means you **were** capable (but didn't), but it may express uncertainty about whether you actually did (or unwillingness to say whether you did or didn't).

Comment: Thank you for the nice explanation. But the OP has got the blue and seems confused:). Could you shed some more light on the first and second examples?

Comment: @Noah: Idiomatically it's common to use present *could* with past *was* in the second one, as I said. It actually "means" *"you would have been able to touch it (if you had been there)"*. Have a look at [some written examples](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22so+close+you+could%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) of *"so close you could"* - you'll see how it's used, and you should soon see that it makes no difference whether it's followed by *"have"* or not.

Comment: ...actually, since you've got me back looking at this answer again, I think I'll have a shot at validly contextualising your second example (I doubt it's anywhere near as easy as you think!)

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. Does it mean you are going to get back to me on this?

Comment: @Noah: Well, I've edited my answer to provide a (somewhat contrived) context where your second example would be valid. I still have no idea what context *you* thought it would be valid in. As I said originally, I don't know what context you were thinking of that made your first one valid, but not the second. They're both valid - where are you having a problem?

Comment: I dont get this. What is the difference between these two: * I could throw this in the recycle bin, but I didn't want to(Past form of can, I was able to throw it). * I could have thrown this in the trash can, but I didn't want to(Same here, at least to my ear). The first one could be confusing if only used by itself. If both are valid which one should I use? For example, I am walking with a friend, holding a soda can in my hand and I just throw it away. The friend looks at me and says 'you could have thrown this in a recycle bin'. And I say 'I could, but I didn't want to'.

Comment: @Noah: You *could **do*** something right now, you *could **have done*** it sometime before. Don't think of *could* as the past tense of *can* - it isn't really, anyway.

Comment: Another question(already asked this but haven't got any answer). What is the difference? *I registered for the event last week but couldn't make it vs. I registered for the event last week but couldn't have made it*

Comment: Or: *I couldn't open the door this morning* vs. *I couldn't have opened the door this morning*

Comment: @Noah: If you *couldn't **have*** done something before, the implication is you *could* now.

Comment: [“It is clear that a division of conditionals into the zero, first, second, and third categories does not adequately reflect actual usage.”](http://clok.uclan.ac.uk/1531/1/elt.ccp101.full_1531.pdf) —from ***“If only it were true: the problem with the four conditionals”,*** Christian Jones and Daniel Waller, *ELT Journal* 65:1 pp 24–32 (2011), Oxford University Press,  doi: 10.1093/elt/ccp101.

Answer (score 1):

It's a question of whether something did happen or was only possible.  Here is a [good resource](http://www.englishgrammarsecrets.com/couldhave/menu.php) explaining how to use 'could have'.  In particular for your examples:

> We can use 'could have' to talk about something somebody was capable of doing but didn't do.

This applies to your example: "We could have walked."

Whereas 'could' is used more as a simple past tense.

> I can hear something scratching in the wall!  (right now)
>
> I could hear something scratching in the wall. (yesterday)

There is also another use of 'could' for capability in the present tense:

> The bus broke down, but we could walk instead.

Comment: What about this: *I registered for the event last week but couldn't make it* vs. *I registered for the event last week but couldn't have made it*

Comment: @Noah: I think that still falls into the "simple past tense" as a simple statement of fact:  I couldn't make it.   But you're right, it doesn't /quite/ fit the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The use of ‘Could Have’
‘Could have’ indicates that something was possible in past, but it did not happen or was not done.
Examples:
I could have got good marks, but I did not labour.
He could have jumped into the river, but then he thought of his children.
You could have got success, but you didn’t try.
You could have counseled the students, but you didn’t have time.

So, 'I could have heard something' indicates that you had the opportunity to hear, but you didn't.