# Is this expression correct "Don't worry about it; it is supposed be one of the features of this year's release"

Tags: meaning, idioms

I have always been little confused regarding the use of *supposed to*. One meaning I am clear on is "obligation," another one is "a theory/concept accepted by a group of people," as in *This restaurant is supposed to be a good one*.

But I can't make any sense out of the sentence given that definition. So is this phrase correct? If so, then how I am supposed to interpret it?

Comment: What does "release" refer to in this sentence? A film festival?

Comment: @tylerharms  I meant as some product like windows 8 but yes it works for film festival too.

Answer (score 7):

*Supposed to* (pronounced /'spostə/) is a periphrastic [modal](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/modals.html) idiom. I.e, it means much the same thing, in much the same contexts, as the modal auxiliary verb *should*.

Like *should*, it must be followed by an infinitive verb (that's what the *to* is for), and it indicates (like *should*) either a mild obligation of the subject to perform an active infinitive (the **deontic** modal sense), or a commonly-held belief in the likelihood of a stative infinitive being true (the **epistemic** sense).

- *(You should/You're supposed to) lock the door behind you.*
- *This (should/is supposed to) be the last one we do.*

Unlike *should*, however, *supposed to* is not a verb but a predicate adjective, and therefore has to be preceded by some form of *be*, which is tensed.  *Should*, a defective modal auxiliary, doesn't allow any tense.

- *You were supposed to lock the door.*
- **You shoulded lock the door.*

All modals have such periphrastic idioms, for the same reasons, often with idiomatic reduced pronunciations, e.g,

- *ought to* /'ɔɾə/ ~ *should*
- *have to* /'hæftə/ ~ *must*
- *want to* /'wanə/ ~ *will*
- *(be) willing to ~ will*
- *(be) able to ~ can*
- *(be) allowed to ~ may*

In the case mentioned, this is the epistemic sense, so it means

> It is a commonly-held belief that this is likely to be one of the features of this year's release.

And that seems to be how it was intended and interpreted.

Comment: This text has an overall typographical emphasis of about 0.26 lawler.[¹](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3408/measuring-typographical-emphasis-the-lawler-and-lawler-weight)

Comment: We did [kick this one around before](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21706/why-do-we-say-was-supposed-to-for-should-have), and I still like [Cerberus's answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/21852/2637) there. But I like this one too (apart from anything else, it's shorter! :)

Answer (score 1):

John Lawler's answer is fabulously detailed, but may be a little hard to follow.

In this sentence, "supposed to" has the meaning of "is expected to."  It's similar to its meaning of obligation -- telling a child "You are supposed to eat your vegetables" could mean either/both of "you are obliged to eat your vegetables" and "you are expected to eat your vegetables."

As Mr. Lawler points out, "should" is often a good replacement.  It has both the "obliged" and "expected" meanings.

Comment: You had me at "John Lawler's answer".

Comment: Umm... Doesn't exactly the same deontic/epistemic ambiguity apply to ***is expected to***? (as well as ***should***, obviously). Explaining one ambiguous word in terms of two others having the same ambiguity seems a bit odd (but I suppose we're supposed to be familiar with how at least *one* of the three works! :)