# Why do "supposed" and "expected" both have similar dual meanings of assumed/predicted or obligated?

Tags: synonyms, homonyms

"You are supposed to pay your taxes"

This could mean that you should pay your taxes, under obligation. It could also mean that someone (probably the speaker) has presumed that you do pay your taxes.

"You are expected to pay your taxes"

Again, this could mean that you should pay your taxes, under obligation. It could also mean that someone (probably the speaker) has presumed that you do pay your taxes.

I've always been fascinated, and annoyed, at the dual meaning of "expect". The presumptive meaning of "suppose" is rare in modern English, so this parallel hasn't been clear to me until recently.

Why would these two different words be synonymous for two different pairs of meanings?

Comment: Because [_sposta_](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/94171/15299) and _expected to_ are [modals](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Modality.pdf), and all modals have both a deontic sense -- obligation -- and an epistemic sense -- assumed/predicted. Just like _must_ can be "obliged" as in _You must attend the meeting_ (deontic), but also "assumed/predicted" as in _This must be the place_ (epistemic).

Comment: @JohnLawler that's an excellent answer. Why post as a comment instead of an answer?

Comment: @JohnLawler: Please post that as an answer, unless you're saving answer #1000 for a special question ;)

Comment: @Tushar: [Already done that, multiple times](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a15299%20modal%20deontic). I get tired of repeating myself. Since nobody finds official answers, I see no reason to differentiate them from comments, which nobody finds, either.

Comment: @JohnLawler expecting me to know the words "modal" and "deontic" when searching for an answer to this problem is ridiculous.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Apologies. I'm sure everyone appreciates your contribution a lot, Sir.

Comment: @Sparr: ELL is where you learn about that, if you didn't learn it in grammar school. This is the stack exchange for people who actually understand something about English grammar. _Modal_ is a standard term and if you don't know it, your education is defective; about like stopping math before algebra. _Deontic_ is a specialized term restricted to modals, but if you read anything about modals it will turn up right away and has to be understood. There are lots of other ways one can search for information in those answers; i just picked the most efficient small search.

Comment: @JohnLawler I'd wager my education and grasp of the English language is in the top 10%, and I've never heard or seen the word 'deontic' before, nor have I ever heard 'modal' applied to language (only to software dialogs). You're talking about things not covered in many college level courses, let alone middle school (where one might encounter algebra).

Answer (score 1):

Because [sposta](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/94171/15299) and expected to are [modals](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/Modality.pdf), and all modals have both a deontic sense -- obligation -- and an epistemic sense -- assumed/predicted. Just like must can be "obliged" as in You must attend the meeting (deontic), but also "assumed/predicted" as in This must be the place (epistemic).

Quoted from @JohnLawler's [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/239125/why-do-supposed-and-expected-both-have-similar-dual-meanings-of-assumed-pred#comment516367_239125) on this question.